# Highlighting the PDF - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, calayer, quartz-graphics

I want to implement a Highlight function in my pdf reader app. Unfortunately, my research yielded very few information about this. However, I came to believe that I will have to use an "overlay" where the drawing or "highlighting" must be done. What I plan to do now is add a CALayer into the pdf. I am successful in rendering shapes into the layer (e.g a simple line, circle, and a square), but I can't seem to draw freely into it (like in Draw Something). Here is the code I used:

When the user begins highlighting:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    prevPoint = [touch locationInView:theContentView];

    drawImageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    drawImageLayer.frame = theContentView.frame;
    [theContentView.layer addSublayer:drawImageLayer];

}
```

When the user is starting the highlighting:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currPoint = [touch locationInView:theContentView];
    drawImageLayer.delegate = self;

    [drawImageLayer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

This is the code where the drawing happens:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{
NSLog(@"DrawLayer being called..");

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currPoint.x, currPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
prevPoint = currPoint;

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

}
```

What happens is that it draws a point and that point follows the cursor everywhere! Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawLayer:` redraws the **entire** layer; it does not keep what was previously drawn. You draw a line from `prevPoint` to `currPoint` then update `currPoint`. Since `drawLayer:` will be called whenever you update `currPoint` (since you call `setNeedsDisplay`), `prevPoint` will be very close to `currPoint`, which is why you basically just see a point following the user's finger.

If you want a straight line starting where the user touched down and ending where the user's finger currently is, you probably want to just get rid of the line
`prevPoint = currPoint;`, which will thus always draw a line from where the user first touched down to where the users' finger currently is.

If you want a smooth line that follows the user's finger, then you'll need to keep track of a list of points, and connect all of them together in `drawLayer`. In practice, since `touchesMoved:` is not called after every single-pixel move, you might have to interpolate a curve that smoothly connects all the points.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things Adam! I will tell you if I made any progress :)